# owl carousel 2.2 dots with aria-label

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I would like to enhance the dots in owl carousel with a 'aria-label' which includes the current image displayed. The final code should look like this:

```
<div class="owl-dot" aria-label="1><span></span></div>
<div class="owl-dot" aria-label="2"><span></span></div>
<div class="owl-dot" aria-label="3"><span></span></div>
```

I'm trying to reach this with a attr method

```
    $('.owl-carousel .owl-dot').attr('aria-label', '+currentIndex.lenght+');
```

but I'm simply not able to achieve the current image number inside the aria label. Is there a counter or currentIndex there for Owl carousel? How can I add it? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can loop through each dot and give it the index of the loop like so:

```
//Go through each carousel on the page
$('.owl-carousel').each(function() {
    //Find each set of dots in this carousel
  $(this).find('.owl-dot').each(function(index) {
    //Add one to index so it starts from 1
    $(this).attr('aria-label', index + 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works well. the only problem I do have now is that I do have multiple owl carousel on the same page so the next gallery the index continues from the last number of the previous gallery. is there a way to reset it to zero?

Comment: @webmaya try the edited code above. the number should start from 1 each time

Comment: You may also want to add arial-label to Your owl-next and owl-prev button. e.g
  `$(this).find('.owl-next').each(function(index) {
      //Add arial-lable to to owl-next
      $(this).attr('aria-label',"Next Slide");
    }); `